# What happens to program when it accesses kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel

I have read about user space and kernel space and how a program's execution path can bring it from user space to kernel space, I suppose an example of this is if my program runs like this

```
Poco::Net::SocketAddress sender;
char buffer[64000];
.
.
.
socket.receiveFrom(buffer, sizeof(buffer), sender);
```

since this call requires accessing the network card, I think it should go into kernel space.

My question is: 
What happens as the program makes the socket.receivefrom(...) call

1. Does the thread go to sleep and give up its core since it is going
   to kernel space and only gets woken up when the char buffer has been
   written
2. Does the thread go directly to kernel space and come back to user space after writing into the char buffer

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370975/does-a-context-switch-occurs-when-an-interrupt-is-fired

Answer (score 0):

1. No. The thread goes to execute kernel code, at kernel-permissions (ring 0 in an x86). The thread might go to "sleep" (i.e. the CPU might go and execute a different program, or will go idle, this depends on what the scheduler decides) inside the kernel. However, it might not go to sleep at all, if, for example, data is already available from the network card. From a user perspective, you know that when the call returns you have your data in the buffer, and you might expect the call to take a while.
2. It depends on the scheduler. You might get an interrupt at any time and execute something else. But generally, yes, you go to the kernel and back.